# Gradient w.r.t. a parameter of a probability distribution; why is the integral (over the support of the random variable values) equal to zero?

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, expected-value

In a lecture on variational inference, I am trying to understand why the final line below is true:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_q [\nabla_\nu g(z;\nu)] &= \mathbb{E}_q [\nabla_\nu \log p(x,z) - \nabla_\nu \log q(z;\nu)]\\
&= - \mathbb{E}_q [\nabla_\nu \log q(z;\nu)] ~ \textrm{($\log p(x,z)$ is not a function of $\nu$)}\\
&= - \int_z q(z; \nu) \nabla_\nu \log q(z;\nu) \\
&= - \int_z \nabla_\nu q(z;\nu)~\textrm{(Log Derivative Trick)}\\
&= 0 ~\textrm{($q(z;\nu)$ is a continuous probability distribution)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

When considering the gradient (w.r.t a parameter $\nu$) of a continuous probability distribution, why is its integral over the range of the random variable $z$ have to equal zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are able to pull the gradient outside the integral, you have
$$- \int_z \nabla_\nu q(z; \nu) \, dz = - \nabla_\nu \int_z q(z; \nu) \, dz = -\nabla_\nu (1) = 0.$$

Comment: Oh, that was simple. Under what situations would you not be able to switch the integral and gradient?

Comment: @Sam [Section A.5 of Durrett's book](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf#page=478) gives some conditions for when you can interchange the derivative and integral. I think they hold in most "nice" situations.